# Convergence of $\sum_{n≥ 1}\left({\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}\right)^n-1}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to determine the convergence of the series $\sum_{n≥ 1}\left({\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}\right)^n-1}\right).$

However, I was considering that when $n$ takes the value of $1$, the series may not be defined; but leaving that fact aside, I wanted to apply the logarithmic criterion by taking

$$L_n=-\log\left(\frac{\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}\right)^n-1}{\log(n)}\right).$$

However, I don't see where the value of $L_n$ tends to, but I can't think of any other idea. Any help please? thanks

Comment: Apply the mvt to show that the general term goes to zero very slow (like $\log n$ more or less) so the series diverges

Comment: Since $$\frac{\left(\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}\right)^n-1}{\frac{1}{n}}\longrightarrow \infty$$ as $n\longrightarrow \infty$ you can find $N$ to make the above quotient $\geq 1$ for all $n$ beyond $N$. Then use direct comparison to deduce your sum diverges.